# Make 'Full HTML' the default text format

Tags: input-formats

How do I make Full HTML the default text format for the administrator? Currently it is Filtered HTML.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If I remember it correctly, the order that the text formats appear (depending on the permissions you as a user have on using the text formats) is set on the example.com/**admin/config/content/formats** page. Just use the cross icon on the left to drag an re-order the various formats. Put the Full HTML on the top to make it the first choice.

Comment: Thank you, I had already done that and wasn't seeing a change, but I cleared the cache and it started working.

Comment: I have the same but it still asks me each time, is there a way to set it as default.